# nth smallest value in a row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and what I would need is 3 new columns "cheapest value" "2ndcheapest value" "3rdcheapest value" showing the cheapest, 2nd and 3rd cheapest amounts, and  3 other columns that contain the name of the cheapest 2nd and 3rd cheapest products.
I could figure out how to create ranking table and how to create a column with lowest amount, but having these extra 6 columns with values and product names would be great help.

```
    product1    product2    product3    product4    product5    purchased   Rating
id                          
1111    1000.0  2000.0  2400.0  5000.0  NaN 2400    Average
1112    2300.0  6000.0  1400.0  4000.0  1000.0  1000    Fair
1113    3000.0  2000.0  NaN NaN 4000.0  2000    Good
1114    4000.0  NaN 1400.0  3000.0  2000.0  2000    Good
1115    3400.0  2400.0  NaN 1400.0  1000.0  1000    Fair
1116    2200.0  2800.0  3500.0  2300.0  4000.0  2300    Average
1117    1000.0  1400.0  3000.0  NaN 2000.0  1400    Fair
1118    NaN 1200.0  1700.0  3000.0  NaN 1700    Good
1119    NaN 2300.0  1900.0  NaN 1100.0  1100    Fair
1120    2300.0  3200.0  NaN 5000.0  1000.0  2300    Average
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the pandas documentation for n-smallest [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)?

Comment: For a small dataset, you can transpose and use `nsmallest`. For a large one, you could try whether directly using numpy can be more efficient...